# PHP request dying silently when writing to stdout

Tags: php, stdout

I have an app that has been working for some time. Just this morning, we started getting a 504 Gateway Timeout error. Cannot get through to anything. Upon stepping through the code, I found it's timing out when attempting to write to `php://stdout`. Changing it to `php://output` works, and dumps it to the screen as you would expect. Changing it to: `STDERR` or `php://stderr` works as you would expect (it writes to the error log).
I've tried an `@` to suppress errors, as well as a try/catch, but it appears that an error is not what's happening. Any ideas for something to try? I'm at a bit of a loss on this one.

Running in ECS (Fargate):

```
PHP: 7.2.26
Apache: 2.4.43
Linux: Alpine 3.8.5
```

Comment: Is it possible to to run an strace -f on the apache process to see if it's getting stuck on something? stdout should be non-blocking, I would suspect something more sinister.

Comment: Trying to use strace was proving to be quite difficult. We're thinking there's a possibility PHP may not be closing the streams to stdout, which would eventually run us into our limit of 4096 handles. I put some things in place to close the stream handler, and the code pipeline re-built the box, so we'll see if this happens again.

Comment: And we hit the issue again. There are 51 open apache processes. Trying to see what we can do to track down what is hanging.

Comment: I haven't looked through all of the (many) change logs between 7.2.26 and 7.4.7 but is there a chance that there was a bug with that quite old version of PHP that has since been fixed? Is it possible to try the latest version to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Which apache MPM are you running?

Comment: Just tried updating to the latest alpine linux, which has php 7.4.7. Apache MPM: prefork. Version: Apache/2.4.43. Again the logs to stdout worked for a while, then stopped and became blocking. I added `stream_set_blocking($handler, false);`, and the site now works, but nothing is logged. It's almost as if the stdout got full. I don't know that's actually possibly, but that's how it acts... except no errors anywhere that we can find. We're able to log to files though, so we changed it to that for right now. We've just spent 2 days trying to write stupid logs!